# elasticsearch why i need to specify routing query parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch 2.3.2 and Lucene 5.5.0.
Some indexes were already existing in my nodes with documents. 
To search them I was using

```
GET /index/type/id
```

But when I created a new index. I have to search with

```
GET /index/type/id?routing=routing_name
```

To search with previous query method how should I create Index. I do see that records mapping structure is same as old data. 
Also, why do I need to specify routing? In previous, it was not the case.

According to ElasticSearch documentation by default, we don't need to specify `routing` as id is default routing parameter. also, I have not specified `{routing: {required: true}}`anywhere while creating an index or adding a record.

Comment: It seems that routing came into action because of some config, upon the new index creation. Have a look at: 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171199/945214

Comment: Are you indexing your documents using custom _route parameter?

Comment: Do you have _routing required in your mapping? e.g. `"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "_routing": {
        "required": true 
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: Did you create a parent-child relationship in your new index?

Comment: please post the mapping for the index which requires routing and does not require routing ? It very well could be  picking it up from index templates ? Would be speculating without the mapping